# ASM| Program exit after Mod(%) is 0 in a calculator project

Tags: assembly, x86, calculator, modulo, divide

In my calcilator projuect I'm doing a Mod action

ex . 15 % 6 = 3

When im doing it and there is a mod (!=0) its working

but when im doing it and the mod is 0 , ex. 100 % 10

the program dont even show that i entered '%' , and just exit.

Full program : http://pastebin.com/zkHw911M (line 168)

OR divide and Mod part:

```
DivideDo:
push ax
;mov ax , word ptr Num1Int
mov ah , 0
mov al , Num1Int
div Num2Int
mov ResultInt , al
pop ax
ret

ModDo:
push ax
;mov ax , word ptr Num1Int
mov ah , 0
mov al , Num1Int
div Num2Int
mov ResultInt , ah
pop ax
ret
```

ScreenShoot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `DoMod` looks okay to me. I suspect your `Int2Str` is the problem. It looks to me that if the result is zero, you `pop` something that hasn't been `push`ed, and don't ever put a '0' in your string. Does a `sub` with a result of zero work? I'm not (conveniently) able to test your code, but I think the `cmp al, 0` should go AFTER the `div`, count the digit, and `push` it - `jnz top` rather than `jmp top`... Subtle bug! Look there, and see if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your "display decimal number" routine has a fatal flaw. It assumes that there will be at least one non-zero digit to display.

```
I1:
                cmp al,0    <-- In the case where the result is zero, you don't push anything on the stack
                je I2
                mov ah,0
                div dl
                push ax
                inc cx
                jmp I1
        I2:
                pop ax
                add ah,30H
                mov [bx] , ah
                inc bx
                loop I2
```